# Return Future[List[DiagnosisCode]] from fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCodes method

Tags: scala, concurrency, user-defined-functions, future, executioncontext

**I am not able to return Future[List[DiagnosisCode]] from fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCodes**

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global  
case class DiagnosisCode(rootCode: String, uniqueCode: String, description: Option[String] = None)

    object Database {

      private val data: List[DiagnosisCode] = List(
        DiagnosisCode("A00", "A001", Some("Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae")),
        DiagnosisCode("A00", "A009", Some("Cholera, unspecified")),
        DiagnosisCode("A08", "A080", Some("Rotaviral enteritis")),
        DiagnosisCode("A08", "A083", Some("Other viral enteritis"))
      )
    
      def getAllUniqueCodes: Future[List[String]] = Future {
        Database.data.map(_.uniqueCode)
      }


      def fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCode(uniqueCode: String): Future[Option[DiagnosisCode]] = Future {
        Database.data.find(_.uniqueCode.equalsIgnoreCase(uniqueCode))
      }
    }
```

*getAllUniqueCodes returns all unique codes from data List.*

*fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCode returns DiagnosisCode when uniqueCode matches.*

- From fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCodes, I would like to return Future[List[DiagnosisCode]] using getAllUniqueCodes() and fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCode(uniqueCode).*

  ```
    def fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCodes: Future[List[DiagnosisCode]] = {

      val xa: Future[List[Future[DiagnosisCode]]] = Database.getAllUniqueCodes.map { (xs: 
          List[String]) =>
        xs.map { (uq: String) =>
          Database.fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCode(uq)
        }
      }.map(n =>
          n.map(y=>
            y.map(_.head))) // Future[List[Future[DiagnosisCode]]]
    }
  ```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code - seems like code blocks and plain text are mixed up.

Comment: Also: assuming you are getting some error (probably a compiler error): what is the error message?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. Your assumption below is correct. Thanks, Accepted your answer.

Comment: Be advised your approach using `head` throws a `NoSuchElementException` if it finds a `None` in the `Option`.

Comment: I have Edited my Code with proper imports and separated code from plain text.
can you post the code for fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCodes: Future[List[DiagnosisCode]] ={???}. for better readability and where the code won't head towards any exception.

Comment: Also for **_.head** can use **_.get** instead

Comment: Using `get` throws the same mentioned exception. Using your `data` it's not possible to simulate it since you extract the unique codes from the same data that you query on, so you will always have a diagnosis for your code. But if you would query on other data, your code will break. You need to state what you need to happen in case there is a unique code for which there is no diagnosis.

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip If there is a unique code that does not match in `fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCode()` method, It will not throw any exception, It will return `None` because `fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCode()` method returns `Future[Option[DiagnosisCode]]`

Comment: That is correct. What I meant to say is that when you will have that `None` you just mentioned, call `.get` or `.head`  from within the last method: `fetchDiagnosisForUniqueCodes()`, it will break. I can show you an example if it's still not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your post correctly, your question is: "How can I convert a `Future[List[Future[DiagnosisCode]]]` into a `Future[List[DiagnosisCode]]`?"

The answer to that question would be: use `Future.sequence`:

```
// assuming an implicit ExecutionContext is in scope:

val xa: Future[List[Future[DiagnosisCode]]] = // ... your code here
val flattened: Future[List[DiagnosisCode]] =
  xa.flatMap { listOfFutures => 
    Future.sequence(listOfFutures)
  }
```